# Will boyer moore maximum vote algorithm fail for certain cases?

Tags: algorithm, boyer-moore

Consider the following array with elements:

```
0  5  1  5  2  5
```

The algorithm does not return 5 as the majority element, but at the end of the first pass considers 2 as the majority element with a count of 0.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
num1 = array[0], count = 0;
for(int n : array){
    if (n == num1)
        count++;
    else if(count == 0)
        num1 = n;
        count = 1;
    else
        count--;
}
```

At the end of this iteration, num1 will contain element '2' and count will be 0.
How should I make the algorithm work to return the element '5'?

Comment: *In its simplest form, the algorithm finds a majority element, if there is one: that is, an element that occurs repeatedly for **more** than half of the elements of the input.* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm)

Comment: Oh, I guess I missed on the part "more than half of the elements in the input".